# How to make a function that can directly read any file and replace itself with the text present, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html file named **main.html** and here is it's source :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
  var openFile = function(event) {
    var input = event.target;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
      var text = reader.result;
      var node = document.getElementById('output');
      node.innerText = text;
      console.log(reader.result.substring(0, 200));
    };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
  };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='file' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
<div id='output'>
...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above markup, I used an input to select files while being in the webpage after load. After I selected my file, the source of the file is inherited in the div with id *output*. But I don't want to select the file in such a way. Being new to **FileLoader()**, I am not understanding what to do !! So, lets consider a function named as **Reader()**, and we can go with it something like this :

```
 document.getElementById("output").innerText = Reader("file://pathtofilerequired/anyfile.anyextension");
```

Thus after the **Reader()** function will read the file, with respect to the source given, it will replace itself with the text or anything present in the file. So can this **Reader()** function be made ? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

if the file is on your server you can use the following:

```
jQuery.get('your_file.txt',function(data){
   document.getElementById("output").innerText = data;
});
```

If you want to pull in from your local system you'll need an upload mechanism in place first.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your_file.txt",
    async: false,
    success: function(data){ 
        document.getElementById("output").innerText = data;
    }
});
```

Uploadind must be realized with backend script.

Comment: Such as .cst , .ctm, .llb or anything ?

Comment: I have tried but jquery ajax doesn't support custom extensions !

Comment: So, that was not helpful as I have to load .tss files

Comment: Again I have no server